# How to pass value to a reference's field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Comment with the code:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :comments
end
```

In my show.html.erb i have this form to create comments with this line:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :comment_id, value: comment.id %>
```

But it ins't setting the comment_id in db.

If i try

```
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, value: comment.id %>
```

This works(parent_id is another field), but i don't want to set parent_id.

**UPDATE**

The problem was in the permitted params.

Comment: Did you paste the code for your Comment model properly? The associations don't seem to be good. A Comment should belong to a Post, and a Post should have many comments.

Comment: Yes, my Post model has a **has_many :comments** line.
My Comment model has **has_many :comments** 'cause is a recursive model.

Comment: I see, so a Post can have many comments, and each of those post's comments can have comments as well. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, is that correct

Comment: Does your Comment table have a comment_id column?

Comment: yes, my comment table has this column

Comment: So your comments table has a post_id column and a comment_id column, that represents the parent of a comment replies, correct?

Comment: An example of my comments table
` #<Comment id: 1, commenter: "Jesus", body: "Ola", post_id: 1, created_at: "2017-04-13 14:27:18", updated_at: "2017-04-13 14:27:18", parent_id: nil, comment_id: nil> `

Comment: Hmm.. why do you need a parent_id and why a comment_id? Shouldn't parent_id be sufficient? parent_id should reference the id of a comment when the comment has children

Comment: Forget about parent_id, it's about another tests that i've made. Now i just use comment_id for recursive purposes.

Comment: Ok, so the problem could be on how you declare the association. Try with `has_many :responses, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: "comment_id"`.
Then you should be able to do `@comment.responses` and get the comments where comment_id matches `@comment.id`. I use `responses` because I think is more clear than `comments`. Please let me know if that helps

Comment: does it comes to controller in params? Do you permit this param?

Comment: @idej this was the problem.. i permitted the param, with the wrong name. 
Thanks.

Comment: @DouglasRodrigues glad to help. Added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be that you haven't permited param in controller with the right name `comment_id`